# WAFv2 WebACLAssociation "The ARN isn't valid" - direct setup works

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-waf

I've been trying to connect my ApiGateway RestApi to my WAF WebACL for some time now.

I am working with the serverless framework so I have the Cloudformation template serverless.yml.

Here is my setup:

```
    MyWafWebACL:
      Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::WebACL'
      Properties:
        Name: 'WhitelistedIPsWebACL'
        Scope: 'REGIONAL'
        DefaultAction:
          Allow: {}
        Rules:
          - Name: 'AllowWhitelistedIPsIPv4'
            Priority: 0
            Action:
              Allow: {}
            Statement:
              IPSetReferenceStatement:
                ARN: !GetAtt MyWafIPSetIPv4.Arn
            VisibilityConfig:
              SampledRequestsEnabled: true
              CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
              MetricName: 'AllowWhitelistedIPsIPv4Metric'
          - Name: 'AllowWhitelistedIPsIPv6'
            Priority: 1
            Action:
              Allow: {}
            Statement:
              IPSetReferenceStatement:
                ARN: !GetAtt MyWafIPSetIPv6.Arn
            VisibilityConfig:
              SampledRequestsEnabled: true
              CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
              MetricName: 'AllowWhitelistedIPsIPv6Metric'
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
          MetricName: 'WhitelistedIPsMetric'

    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
      Properties:
        Name: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
        Description: 'Standard REST gateway'

    MyWafWebACLAssociation:
      Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation'
      Properties:
        WebAclArn: !Ref MyWafWebACL
        ResourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}::/restapis/${ApiGatewayRestApi}/stages/dev"
```

When commenting out the WebACLAssociation everything deploys fine and the resources are created correctly. I can also make the association in the web interface without issue but I want to deploy to different stages and having to do this manually when it should work normally is error-prone and I would like to avoid it at all cost.

I have tried the following:

- Use the ResourceArn directly as in no !Sub but the exact ARN -> "ARN isn't valid"
- Use the ResourceArn with the id of the Path "/" -> "Resource doesn't exist"
- Use various other formats of creating the ResourceArn like fn join etc. -> "ARN isn't valid"

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer when searching through repost.

It is mentioned [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUzpvTS6I6RXee9qmsdEz3lQ/can-t-associate-webacl-to-api-gateway-by-cloudformation) that the issue is not the ResourceArn of the apigateway but the WebAclArn. The error messages being thrown are wrong.

The WebAclArn cannot be referenced like `!Ref MyWafWebACL` because this seems to be an object with multiple values. The correct reference is `!GetAtt MyWafWebACL.Arn` which points to the arn directly.

This solved my issues.